# How use PQexecParams in libpq?

Tags: sql, c, database, postgresql, libpq

I've read the document but still I'm confused how use this function to send this command to server:

```
INSERT INTO table_1($1,$2,$3);
```

this function I wrote:

```
void add_data_to_db(char table){
        const char data[2][2] = {"12","me"};
        re = PQexecParams(connection,
                        "INSERT INTO test_table($1,$2)",
                        2,data,NULL,NULL,NULL,0
                        );
}
```

but during the compile this error occurs:

```
db.c: In function ‘add_data_to_db’:
db.c:40:6: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘PQexecParams’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   40 |    2,data,NULL,NULL,NULL,0
      |      ^~~~
      |      |
      |      const char (*)[2]
In file included from db.c:2:
/usr/include/libpq-fe.h:391:18: note: expected ‘const Oid *’ {aka ‘const unsigned int *’} but argument is of type ‘const char (*)[2]’
  391 | extern PGresult *PQexecParams(PGconn *conn,
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html) describes `PQexecParams`:

> ```
> PGresult *PQexecParams(PGconn *conn,
>                        const char *command,
>                        int nParams,
>                        const Oid *paramTypes,
>                        const char * const *paramValues,
>                        const int *paramLengths,
>                        const int *paramFormats,
>                        int resultFormat);
> ```

The parameter values are *not* the fourth, but the fifth argument.

The fourth argument, if not left `NULL`, is an array with the object IDs describing the types of the parameters.

Note that in C, a string like `"me"` does not occupy two, but three bytes (you have to include the final zero byte).